# Create database via ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, mfc, odbc

How do you create new database using MFC ODBC API?

In the connection string you should mention the name of the database you want to connect to. What if I have just-installed SQL Server containing no user databases?

Which database name do you specify in the connection string?

E.g. for SQL Server:

```
    CDatabase db;

    db.OpenEx(L"Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;"
              L"Database=????????;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword", CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);

    db.ExecuteSQL(L"CREATE DATABASE testdb");
```

Should I use System Databases (e.g. master, model, etc.)?
Is there some more generic approach?

Comment: you can replace ???????? with "master" ... the master db  allways exists

Comment: master db allways exists... true for SQL Server / MySQL, but doesn't work for PostgreSQL

Comment: Your question is specifically asking about SQL Server. If you need a solution for other database drivers as well, you should explicitly list those requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit `Database=` in the connection string. Then you create a new database and after that you switch to that database using `USE`.

Something like this works fine for me:

```
SQLWCHAR     strConnect[256] = L"Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\\MACHINE;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
SQLWCHAR     strConnectOut[1024] = { 0 };
SQLSMALLINT nNumOut = 0;
SQLRETURN nResult = SQLDriverConnect(handleDBC, NULL, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnect, SQL_NTS, (SQLWCHAR*)strConnectOut, sizeof(strConnectOut), &nNumOut, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
    // some error handling

SQLHSTMT    handleStatement = SQL_NULL_HSTMT;
nResult = SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, handleDBC, (SQLHANDLE*)&handleStatement);
if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(nResult))
    // some error handling

// Create a new database and use that
nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"CREATE DATABASE Foobar", SQL_NTS);
nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"USE Foobar", SQL_NTS);

// create table Wallet in database Foobar
nResult = SQLExecDirect(handleStatement, L"CREATE TABLE Wallet (WalletID int NOT NULL,  Name nvarchar(5) NOT NULL)", SQL_NTS);
```