# With Powershell create new Pervasive ODBC with new database

Tags: windows, odbc, pervasive

I would like to create in Powershell a 32 bits ODBC connection to a Pervasive Database. I have the following that works:

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "dbcon" -DriverName "Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface" -DsnType "User" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue "Dbq=GENERAL"
```

The problem is that I want to create a new database pointing to a specific folder. Steps in the UI.

[image]

Hit create.

[image]

Fill in the dictionary location.

**NOTE**

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "dbcon" -DriverName "Pervasive ODBC Engine Interface" -DsnType "User" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("DBALIAS=GENERAL2","Description=General","DictionaryLocation=C:\mylocation","DataFileLocation=C:\mylocation")
```

And it gave the following error:

> Add-OdbcDsn : Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator
> failed (Installer error code: 11).

Comment: I'm not sure there's a way to create the database from PowerShell.  Even the built-in tool DBMAINT is only available on Linux and MacOS.  You might be able to use PowerShell to call the DTO (DIstributed Tuning Object) COM interface to create a database then create the ODBC DSN.

Comment: You need to combine these two answers:  [Cannot create database with odbc connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57390773/cannot-create-database-with-odbc-connection)  and [Create database via ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824066/create-database-via-odbc)

Answer (score 0):

I did do some fiddling in Powershell, and this creates a database:

I tested with "Zen Enterprise v15 Community Edition 1-user for Linux 64-bit." but this should work with other versions too.

`$database`, `$dictionary_path`, `$data_path` and SERVERNAME need to be changed to your likings.

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Actian\Zen\bin\ADONET4.5\Pervasive.Data.Common.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Actian\Zen\bin\ADONET4.5\Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.dll"

$p = new-object Pervasive.Data.SqlClient.PsqlConnection("server=SERVERNAME")
$p.Open()
$database = "TEST"
$dictionary_path = "/usr/local/actianzen/data/TEST"
$data_path = "/usr/local/actianzen/data/TEST"
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $database DICTIONARY_PATH '$dictionary_path' DATA_PATH '$data_path' "

$cmd = $p.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandText = $sql
$x = $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

$p.Close();
```